# Genogram distance between any 2 nodes in Go Js

Tags: gojs

I have builded below genogram using go js library & my goal is to find distance of levels between any 2 nodes

[image]

Below links is what i have tried & but one of hurdle is my graph is genogram & the examples link below are linear nodes graphs hence distance is more easy to calculate.

From above graph one of note point is you can see 2 nodes with 0 & 1 ideally the node below it distance should be 1 & above distance should be 1 but its infinity since in genogram the any one spouse can have children hence other spouse distance to that child will be infinity.

Distance & path examples in genogram :

```
https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/distances.html
https://gojs.net/latest/intro/links.html
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/distances.html
```

Anyways my goal is how to achieve distance between two nodes in genogram type of graph in go js & any clue or alternative path is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole graph is connected -- in other words if there is some path of links and nodes between the two nodes in question, then I suppose you could just look at the difference in their **Node.location** Y values to determine how many generations different they are.

This seems to be a duplicate of https://forum.nwoods.com/t/genogram-distance-between-any-2-nodes-in-go-js/13889

If you want to traverse the graph in order to find the relationship(s) between two nodes, please read https://forum.nwoods.com/t/is-there-any-way-to-find-lowest-common-ancestor-in-genogram/10474/2.